# Adding new nested div to document

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a div with a child div to the document but append() seems to be the wrong option for this, what should I use instead?

```
  //Create Statusbar
  var status = $('#status');
  for (var i = 0; i < resources.length; i++) {
    var resource = document.createElement('div');
    var resourceCounter = document.createElement('div');
    resourceCounter.id = "r" + (i + 1);
    //resource.className = "resource";
    resource.innerHTML = resources[i];
    resourceCounter.innerHTML = saveData.resources ? saveData.resources[i] : 0;
    resource.style.background = "url('images/resources/" + resource.id + ".jpg') 0 26px / 100% auto no-repeat";
    resource.onclick = function () {
      alert(this.id);
    };
    resource.append(resourceCounter);
    status.append(resource);
  }
```

`resource.append(resourceCounter);` --> Uncaught TypeError: Object #HTMLDivElement has no method 'append'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here resource is a dom element, append is a method provided by jQuery, it is not present in the dom element

you can use [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) instead

```
resource.appendChild(resourceCounter);
```

or wrap resouces with jQuery and use append

```
$(resource).append(resourceCounter);
```